# How to format an image tag within a template when using streams with LiipImagineBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.4, liipimaginebundle, gaufrette

If I configure [LiipImagineBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle) to use a [stream data loader](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/data-loader/stream.md), How do I then craft an image tag to use that data loader within a template?

**Updated Config**

```
knp_gaufrette:
adapters:
    image_storage:
        amazon_s3:
            amazon_s3_id: namespace_admin.amazon_s3
            bucket_name:  %amazon_s3_bucket_name%
            create:       false
            options:
                create:     true
                directory: 'mydir'
                region:     %amazon_s3_region%


filesystems:
    image_storage:
        adapter:    image_storage
        alias:      image_storage_filesystem

    s3_storage:
        adapter:    image_storage

stream_wrapper:
        protocol: data
        filesystems:
            - s3_storage



namespace_admin:
    amazon_s3:
        aws_key:        %amazon_aws_key%
        aws_secret_key: %amazon_aws_secret_key%
        aws_region:     %amazon_s3_region%
        base_url:       %amazon_s3_base_url%

liip_imagine:
    loaders:
        stream.my_namespace_images:
            stream:
                wrapper: data://s3_storage

resolvers:
   default:
      web_path: ~

filter_sets:
    cache: ~
    gi_thumb:
        data_loader: stream.my_namespace_images
        quality: 75
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound }
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things, you need to do.

1. The `gi_thumb` filter needs to set the `data_loader` to `stream.get_inspired_images`.
2. In your template you just call the `imagine_filter` on a file path that's loadable by that loader: `{{ '/example/path/image.png'|imagine_filter('gi_thumb', true) }}`

This would load this image: `http://your-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/example/path/image.png`.

Comment: also imagine_filter('gi_thumb', true) is incorrect as the second param needs to be an array